# Why the value of the selected tab is not consistent?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-tabs

I have noticed is that when I click every tab its value is not consistent - **why**?

I want to get the index of the tab 'Sign out'. What should I do to make it consistent?

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
        var selected = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected');
        alert(selected);
    });
});
```

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="tabs" class="login-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Messages">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Notifications">Notifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Find">Find Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Signout">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Home">

    </div>
    <div id="Profile">

    </div>
    <div id="Messages">

    </div>
    <div id="Notifications">

    </div>
    <div id="Find">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var index = $('#tabs ul').index($('#tabs a[href="#Signout"]'));

if($('#tabs a[href="#Signout"]').parent('li').hasClass('ui-tabs-selected'))
    //signout tab selected
```

Comment: why is not consistent? so that I will just code like if(selected == '1')

Comment: @BrainedWashed Well, as long as its the 6th `li`, you should get 6 as index. Or 5 if it starts at 0.

Comment: but why is that is it not consistent? Am I missing something? Or any other way to know if a certain tab is clicked? thanks!